# Can I integrate JQuery in Spring Roo Web project?

Tags: jquery, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo for a web-mvc project. I require auto-completion feature that needs JQuery call. It seems like the jquery call is not working.

Now I have doubt, whether Spring Roo supports jquery.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks,

Chandan

Answer (score 0):

You can use gvNIX project, it is a Roo 1.2.4 distribution that includes its own add-ons, one of them is an add-on that move your project from Dojo to jQuery

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/QuickStartGvnix